# How to call an Oracle Function using oracle .Net provider?

Tags: .net, oracle, function, call, provider

When i use old Oracle Dll in my .net mvc project it works:

```
   cmd.CommandText = "dba.user_login";
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("KUL", OracleType.VarChar).Value = userName;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("SIFRE", OracleType.VarChar).Value = pass;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("FLAG", OracleType.Float).Value = 1;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("HATA", OracleType.VarChar).Value = "error";
   cmd.Parameters.Add("result", OracleType.Float).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

But i want to use new oracle .net provider because of old oracle dll deprecated.  i tried this :

```
   cmd.CommandText = "dba.user_login";
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("KUL", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = userName;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("SIFRE", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = pass;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("FLAG", OracleDbType.Single).Value = 1;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("HATA", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = "error";
   cmd.Parameters.Add("result", OracleDbType.Single).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

But it not works. Exception: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error\nORA-06512: at line 1
Can anybody help me to fix this. Thank you.

Comment: go ahead and post the definition of the function you are calling.  Keep in mind that ODP.net (I suspect this is the 'new oracle provider' you are referring to) binds by position by default (a break from the default System.Data.Ora does) -- you may use BindByName = true to force the command object to behave the same.

Comment: i'm using 11.2.0  ODP.net (Oracle.DataAccess.dll). i inserted BindByName = true =>
and it works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fantastic, that one design decision always leads to issues at the start of using it (and occassionally down the road!)

Since this answered your question I'll 'promote' my comment to an answer (if that isn't proper let me know and I'll delete this answer)

Keep in mind that ODP.net binds by position by default (a break from the default System.Data.Ora does) -- you may use

```
BindByName = true
```

to force the command object to behave the same

Comment: for the record, one last thing: when i call storedprocedure using System.Data.Ora, cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() returns 1 but now i'm using ODP.net and cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() returns -1. Why return value changed 1 to -1 i don't know but according to MSDN ExecuteNonQuery will always return -1 for stored procedure calls. Thank you again.

Comment: have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955632/return-value-of-oracle-dataaccess-execute-non-query-stored-proc/6957005#6957005